# how to get touchevent for mainwindow in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing an application for arm board. I have a mainwindow and I need to get the touch co-ordinates for single touch. Due to lack of Qt knowledge I am facing a problem of getting the touch event.

As per the QTouchEvent Class document, I have declared a slot as below.

```
#include <QTouchEvent>
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(int x, int y, QWidget *parent = 0);
public slots:
  void touchEvent(QTouchEvent *ev);
};
```

and in mainwindow.cpp I redefine it as below. The FFLabel[1] is already declared by me and I am writing it to confirm if the event is received.

```
void MainWindow::touchEvent(QTouchEvent *ev)
{
  ui->FFLabel[1]->setText(QString("Event"));
  switch (ev->type())
  {
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
    case QEvent::TouchEnd:
    case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
    {

    }
  }
}
```

I am not able to get the touchEvent. Can someone please help me.

I have verified the /dev/input/event2 and am receiving the event there.

Answer (score 4):

`QWidget` has a number of [protected virtual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#protected-functions) members, e.g., `QWidget::mousePressEvent`. They are called when the event occurs.
Usually one overrides such a function to run some code when a certain event happens.

The problem is, that, unlike for mouse press, there is no such virtual function `QWidget::touchEvent` (as of Qt 5.12).  That is, you can't override it and it cannot be called when a touch event happens as `QWidget` is not aware of such a method.

C++11 introduced the [`override`-keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override). If you had used it, you would have noticed that issue.

In order to receive touch events, you must override the more general `QWidget::event` method. Then filter for the events you're actually interested in:

```
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent* event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
        qDebug() << "touch!";
        return true;
    default:
        // call base implementation
        return QMainWindow::event(event);
    }
}
```

Note that you must state `setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);` in order to receive any touch events (put it in the `MainWindow`-constructor).

You can read [more details in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html#details).

Answer (score 3):

Events aren't slots. Declare it as a protected function.

```
 protected:
      void touchEvent(QTouchEvent *ev);
```

Edit: And you didn't put anything in your `switch` statement to show if you get the event.

```
void MainWindow::touchEvent(QTouchEvent *ev)
{
  switch (ev->type())
  {
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
        ui->FFLabel[1]->setText("Event began.");
        break;
    case QEvent::TouchEnd:
        ui->FFLabel[1]->setText("Event ended.");
        break;
    case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
    {
        ui->FFLabel[1]->setText("Event updated.");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: If it's still not working, it means your mainwindow isn't accepting touch events. You need to do this in your mainwindow's constructor:

```
 setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I changed it but still not getting the event.

Comment: See my last edit if you aren't running the program from the command line.

Comment: Actually my code is a daemon and will not be able to print to the shell, hence can't use qDebug(). For this reason I am using the FFLabel to set the text if at all that routine gets called.

Comment: I am not getting that in FFLabel as Event i.e. the routine is not getting called. that is what is my problem

Comment: Did you try setting attribute of mainwindow? See the end of my answer. The last edit.

Comment: If all of this didn't work for you. I'm sorry, this is all I can do. Good luck. You might want to look at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtouchevent.html

Comment: Hey thanks for you help, Although it doesnt work for me. I am seeing if there is any issue towards cross compiling with tslib.

Comment: I have cross compiled qt again with tslib. Now I am able to see the demo apps working with touch, but am not able to get touch events in my application. Do you have a small application that just accepts the touch event and then displays on screen, that will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer:
I had a similar issue and this is not a solution but may be a workaround depending on what you want to do.

In my case, the touch events were interpreted as mouse events so, `MainWindow::touchEvent` was never called but, the mouse events handler were.

I used `MainWindow::mousePressEvent` to get the touch point and `MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent` to get the drag.

This does not handle the multi-touch (it works for the separate contact points but you will have only one move event for all your points)

From Qt5.4, one may try (I didn't test as I'm stuck with Qt4), in the mouse events handler, to check the `MouseEventSource` If it's `MouseEventSynthesizedBySystem` it means [from the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html) that:

> the mouse event was synthesized from a touch event by the platform.

One can find more details checking this solution provided by Chirag Sachdeva in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28449543/1096225)

And of course, with regards to the OP code, as user4516901 said, events aren't slots.