# Signal for scrollbar value changed in qtextedit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am practicing some GUI programming. I would like to scroll 2 qtextedit at the same time.

my problem is i could not find the SIGNAL for verticalscrollbarvaluechanged.

```
connect(ui->textEdit,SIGNAL(....),this,SLOT(scroll());
```

i have this code for the SLOT

```
void MainWindow::scroll()
{

ui->textEdit->verticalScrollBar()->valueChanged(ui->textEdit2->verticalScrollBar()->value());
ui->textEdit2->verticalScrollBar()->valueChanged(ui->textEdit->verticalScrollBar()->value());

}
```

also is there a way to hide the scrollbar? just make it look transparent, but it still there?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not create a new slot, you must use the signal of a scrollbar with the slot of the other and vice versa.

```
connect(ui->textEdit->verticalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)), ui->textEdit_2->verticalScrollBar(), SLOT(setValue(int)));
connect(ui->textEdit_2->verticalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)), ui->textEdit->verticalScrollBar(), SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

Comment: Thank you sir it worked! i understand now. This also solves my problem in my 2nd question, because i thought that if the scrollbar is turned off it would not scroll since there is no scrollbar, but it is not the case

Comment: Can i ask a followup question? If i want it to upload it an android device and just want to drag to scroll what event should i read about? with the one you just taught me the desired result would be flicking through the textedit and both of them will scroll

Comment: What object handles the touchscreen?

Comment: im using Qmainwindow

Comment: I do not mean that, but the object that handles the touchscreen.

Comment: I do not fully understand the question. The device that i will be using is a smartphone ( sony xperia) running on andriod. i this what you ment?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449475/how-to-get-touchevent-for-mainwindow-in-qt ,  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent-touchpoint.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help sir! it will take a little bit of time for me to get this but nonetheless thank you